# class in a private/custom package is not callable when imported

Tags: python-3.x

I have a git repo containing my custom python package.
I install it using pip

```
pip install git+https://github.com/xxxx/my-package.git
```

The package name is mytest
the code is under src/mytest and it contains 3 files

```
simple.py
def add_one(number):
    return number + 1

hard.py
def add_one(number):
    return number + 1

myclass.py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, something):
```

I open a python shell and I type

```
from mytest import simple, hard
simple.add_one(1)
hard.add_one(1)
```

so far so good, then I run into trouble using MyClass

```
from mytest import MyClass

mportError: cannot import name 'MyClass' from 'mytest'
```

why does it work with simple functions and not a class?
What am I missing?

Comment: You are trying to import the class directly from the package instead of the (sub)-module. You want ```from mytest import myclass``` Then you can instantiate with ```myclass.MyClass(...)```

Comment: Or ```from mytest.myclass import MyClass```

Comment: you should do 'import myclass' because the name of the python file is myclass not MyClass

Comment: rom mytest.myclass import MyClass worked, thank you @lemonhead. If you answer the question, I will accept and you get the "credit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to import the class directly from the package instead of the (sub-)module. You want:

```
from mytest import myclass
```

Then you can instantiate with the `myclass` namespace, i.e.

```
kls = myclass.MyClass(...)
```

Same as with your functions

Alternatively, if you want to reference `MyClass` directly you can use

```
from mytest.myclass import MyClass
kls = MyClass(...)
```